# Three.JS Black screen on attaching camera to a GLTF object

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I am writing a bit of stuff if Three.JS and I seem to have hit a stump with the camera. I'm attempting to attach the camera to an imported model object and it would seem that it IS attaching, however it would seem as if shadows are negated, the distance is far off from the actual field I've created. As well as some other annoying issues like Orbit controls would be inverted and non-functional. Here is my code (with certain things blocked out because I'm hotlinking script files hosted on my server...):

```js
// This is basically everything to setup for a basic THREE.JS field to do our work in
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); // Empty Space
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000); // Perspective Camera (Args, FOV, Aspect = W/H, Min View Dist, Max View Dist)
//var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera); // We will use this to look around
camera.position.set(0, 2, 5); // Note that depth into positon is mainly the opposite of where you normally want it to be.
camera.rotation.x = -0.3 // This is an attempt to rotate the angle of the camera off of an axis
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true}); // Our Renderer + Antialiasing
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; // This allows shadows to work in our 3D animation
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // This one isn't as blocky as THREE.PCFShadowMap
renderer.setClearColor("#00CCCC"); // Note: same as 0x000000
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); // Renderer Dimensions
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(renderer.domElement); // Add our renderer creation to our div named "container"
// Lighting (It's not necessary but it looks cool!)
var light = new THREE.PointLight("#FFFFFF", 5, 1000); // Color, intensity, range(lighting will not exceed render distance)
light.castShadow = true;
light.position.set(5, 5, 0); // This will treat the light coming from an angle!
scene.add(light);
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 512;
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 512;
light.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;
light.shadow.camera.far = 500;
// We will make a cube here
var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1); // This is the shape, width, height and length of our cube. Note BoxGeometry IS the current shape!
var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: "#FF0000"}); // Create a basic mesh with undefined color, you can also use a singular color using Basic rather than Normal, There is also Lambert and Phong. Lambert is more of a Matte material while Phong is more of a gloss or shine effect.
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat); // Create the object with defined dimensions and colors!
cube.castShadow = true; // This will allow our cube to cast a shadow outward.
cube.recieveShadow = false // This will make our cube not recieve shadows from other objects (Although it isn't needed because it's default, you show make a habit of writing it anyways as some things default to true!)
scene.add(cube); // scene.add(object) is what we will use for almost every object we create in THREE.JS
//cube.add(camera); // This is an attempt to attach the camera to the cube...
// Loader
var ship;
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load("http://ipaddress:port/files/models/raven/scene.gltf", function(gltf) {
 scene.add(gltf.scene);
 ship = gltf.scene;
 ship.scale.multiplyScalar(0.005);
 ship.rotation.y = Math.PI;
}, undefined, function(error) {
 console.error(error);
});
// Lest make a floor to show the shadow!
var floorGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1000, 0.1, 1000);
var floorMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: "#0000FF"});
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeo, floorMat);
floor.recieveShadow = true; // This will allow the shadow from the cube to portray itself unto it.
floor.position.set(0, -3, 0);
scene.add(floor);
// Now let's create an object on the floor so that we can distance ourself from our starting point.
var buildingGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 100, 10);
var buildingMat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var building = new THREE.Mesh(buildingGeo, buildingMat);
building.position.z = -100;
scene.add(building);
var rotation = 0;
// Controls
var keyState = {};

window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = true;
},true);

window.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = false;
},true);
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  console.log(event.which);
});
var camAdded = false;
var render = function() {
 requestAnimationFrame(render); // This grabs the browsers frame animation function.
 if (rotation == 1) {
  ship.rotation.x += 0.01; // rotation is treated similarly to how two dimensional objects' location is treated
  ship.rotation.y += 0.01; // however it will be based on an axis point plus the width/height and subtract but keep it's indice location!
  ship.rotation.z += 0.01;
 }
 if (keyState[87]) { // Up
  ship.rotateX(0.01);
 }
 if (keyState[83]) { // Down
  ship.rotateX(-0.01);
 }
 if (keyState[65]) { // Left
  ship.rotateY(0.03);
 }
 if (keyState[68]) { // Right
  ship.rotateY(-0.03);
 }
 if (keyState[81]) {
  ship.rotateZ(0.1);
 }
 if (keyState[69]) {
  ship.rotateZ(-0.1);
 }
 if (keyState[82]) { // Reset
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   if (!ship.rotation.x == 0) {
    if (ship.rotation.x > 0) {
     ship.rotation.x -= 0.005;
    } else if (ship.rotation.x < 0){
     ship.rotation.x += 0.005;
    }
   }
   if (!ship.rotation.z == 0) {
    if (ship.rotation.z > 0) {
     ship.rotation.z -= 0.01;
    } else if (ship.rotation.z < 0){
     ship.rotation.z += 0.01;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 ship.translateZ(0.2); // This will translate our ship forward in the direction it's currently facing so that it will look as if it is flyimg.
 renderer.render(scene, camera); // This will render the scene after the effects have changed (rotation!)
 window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}
render(); // Finally, we need to loop the animation otherwise our object will not move on it's own!
function onWindowResize() {
 var sceneWidth = window.innerWidth - 20;
 var sceneHeight = window.innerHeight - 20;
 renderer.setSize(sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
 camera.aspect = sceneWidth / sceneHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE htm>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic Three.JS</title>
 </head>
 <body style="background-color: #2B2B29; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
   window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("container").width = window.innerWidth - 20;
    document.getElementById("container").height = window.innerHeight - 20;
   }
  </script>
  <script src="http://ipaddress:port/files/scripts/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ipaddress:port/files/scripts/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ipaddress:port/files/scripts/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ipaddress:port/files/scripts/basicthree.js"></script> <!-- This is the code below -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found a solution - shoddy as it may be...

```js
if (typeof ship != "undefined") {
  // Previous code inside of the main three.js loop...
  ship.translateZ(0.2); // Move ship
  camera.position.set(ship.position.x, ship.position.y, ship.position.z); // Set the camera's position to the ships position
  camera.translateZ(10); // Push the camera back a bit so it's not inside the ship
  camera.rotation.set(ship.rotation.x, ship.rotation.y, ship.rotation.z); // Set the rotation of the ship to be the exact same as the ship
  camera.rotateX(0.3); // Tilt the camera downwards so that it's viewing over the ship
  camera.rotateY(Math.PI); // Flip the camera so it's not facing the head of the ship model.

  // Note: many bits of code I have are inverted due to the ship's model being backwards (or so it seems)...
}
```